# PHP-FPM as a dedicated application server?

Tags: php, nginx, web-server, php-fpm, scalability

Just wondering in terms of scalability .. do you reckon PHP-FPM should run on a standalone server or works as well if you run it with NginX on the same server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for scalability, run them on dedicated instances, so you can scale up the tiers independently.

Comment: so split up nginx and php-fpm on individual servers?

Comment: That's what I said, yes.